# Bash Child/Parent Pipe Inheritance Exploit

Tags: bash, posix, exploit

```
#!/bin/bash 
ipaddr=${1}
rdlnk=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/0)
user="" 
passwd=""   
function get_input() {
 if grep -Eq "^pipe:|deleted" <<< "${rdlnk}" || [[ -p "${rdlnk}" ]]; then 
  while IFS= read -r piped_input || break; do 
  [[ -z "${ipaddr}" ]] && ipaddr="${piped_input}" && continue
  [[ -z "${user}" ]]   && user="${piped_input}"   && continue
  [[ -z "${passwd}" ]] && passwd="${piped_input}" && continue  
  done  
 fi 
 echo "Got that IP address you gave me to work on: ${ipaddr}" 
 [[ -n "${user}" ]] && echo "[... and that user: ${user}]" 
 [[ -n "${user}" ]] && echo "[... and that users password: ${passwd}]" 
}
get_input 
exit 0
```

Normally it's fine:

```
$> process_ip.bsh 71.123.123.3
Got that IP address you gave me to work on: 71.123.123.3
```

But, put the parent into a piped loop and watch out:

```
$ echo -en "71.123.123.3\nroot\ntoor\n" | while read a; do echo "Parent loop, processing: ${a}"; grep -q '^[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}' <<< "${a}" && ./process_ip.bsh "$a"; done

Parent loop, processing: 71.123.123.3
Got that IP address you gave me to work on: 71.123.123.3
[... and that user: root]
[... and that users password: toor]
```

Ouch. The parent only wanted to provide the IP Address from its pipe to the child. Presuming that the parent must maintain an open pipe with sensitive data in it at the time of the fork to the child process. How can this be prevented?

Comment: Of course the stock answer is never to use clear-text passwords, But assuming the parent and child are running under the same user id, what's the issue?  A user can only access the processes running under their user id (unless root).  If you can gain access to a process then there are several ways to look at clear-text data, not just this one.

Comment: But the parent launches the child.  Why would a parent process launch an unknown child program?  BTW, many UNIX-like operating systems don't have the symbolic links available, I think this would only work on Linux.  OS X, for example, does not have a /proc.

Comment: Launch something like `strace -p $PPID`, or `gdb bash $PPID` and we can see even more.

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming the parent knows ahead of time, or can determine, what incoming data is meant for the child and what is not. If that's the case, the parent is responsible for filtering the input before the child can read it.

Comment: @cdarke That works before yama/ptrace_scope.

Comment: @chepner The parent is trying to perform filtering, but because the data is in the pipe there is no way for the parent to stop the child from reading (and consuming) the parents' sensitive pipe data. The parent has no further say on what the child process does with the dup'd open fd's including the pipe it passed on the fork (as per POSIX).

Comment: Of course you can stop it: `process_ip.bsh < /dev/null`. It's not duping the parent's fd directly; it's just using what it inherits from the parent. (`$$` isn't the caller, because `process_ip.bsh` is a different process, not just a subshell.) Instead of `/dev/null`, of course, you can just pipe from the filter: `filter_input | process_ip.bsh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process_ip.bsh`, like any other process, inherits its standard input from its parent. This line

```
rdlnk=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/0)
```

doesn't do exactly what you think it does. It only contains the name of the file the parent is using for standard input because the script is inheriting its standard input from the parent. (`$$` is the process ID of the current shell because `.process_ip.bsh` is a separate process, not merely a subshell started by the parent.)

If you redirect input to `process_ip.bsh`, you are in complete control of what it receives.

```
while read a; do
    echo "Parent loop, processing: ${a}"
    grep -q '^[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}' <<< "${a}" &&
      ./process_ip.bsh "$a" < /dev/null
done <<EOF
71.123.123.3
root
toor
EOF
```